# While loop is not breaking, what am I missing?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am using a while loop with if elif & else. however, it's not breaking out of first loop. I feel I am not putting break at the right place. Any suggestions?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

while True:
    Answer = 'yes'
    #Answer = input("Are you using an API key? Yes/No ").lower()
    if Answer == 'yes':
        # API = input("Please enter the API key.")
        # SD = input('Please enter the start date')
        # ED = input('Please enter the end date within 10 days of range')
        API = "apikey"
        SD = "2022-09-12"
        ED = "2022-09-21"
        FilePath = open("ConfigFiles2.csv")
        CSV_File = csv.reader(FilePath)
        #CSV_File.next()
        header = next(CSV_File)
        #for row in (CSV_File, unit='Center', desc='Loading'):
        for row in CSV_File:
            #sleep(0.001)
            CID = row[0]
            CenterName = row[1]
            
            try:
                url = testurl
                url2 = testurl2 
                payload={}
                payload2={}
                headers = {'Authorization': f"{API}"}
                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers, data=payload2)
                BlockoutJson = response.json()
                Scheduledata = response2.json()
                #print (BlockoutJson)
                #print (Schedule)
                for i in BlockoutJson['block_out_times']:
                    print(i['employee']['id'], end = ",")
                for i in (Scheduledata['employee_schedules']):
                    sleep(0.001)
                    dst = i['schedules']
                    for d in dst:
                        final = d['shifts']
                        for g in final:
                            print(i['employee_id'], end = ',')
                            print(i['employee_name'], end = ',')
                            print('Schedule', end = ',')
                            print(g['start_time'], end = ',') 
                            print(g['end_time'], end = ',')
                            print(CenterName)
                            break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Though I am giving break at the end of the loop, however, it's not breaking.

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the loop that it's in. It's not clear exactly what you want to happen instead. What is "the first loop"? Also: is it really necessary to have this much code in order to explain the problem? Please read [mre].

Comment: Putting `break` there will only break out from the for loop. To break out from the while loop. you should put the `break` outside of first `if` statement.

Comment: @ShakyaDissanayake - Thank you so much, that's what I was not able to understand where to break the loop. you answer has guided me to the right direction... Thank you once again! 

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - thank you for guiding me. I would go through the link and will follow it. Thank you for suggestions and help